# Bootstrap CSS Style Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying figure out how to adjust some of the bootstrap CSS styling to fix an issue I am running into.

I am using the page header class to create my title which is consistent across all my pages.

On the page I am working on, there is some more information I would like to add to the right side of the page within the header.

Anytime I try to get it to appear above the line, it just goes below or in the middle and the line doesnt seem to move.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rka18Lze/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3 class="text-info">A page header here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 text-right">
      <h5 class="text-info">Owner: <a href="#" target="_blank">Bob Smith</a></h5>
      <h5 class="text-info">Type: Desktop</h5>
      <h5 class="text-info">Status: Active</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

Is there a way I can move the line down under this text; or maybe a special class to help in this one situation if needed?

[image]

Comment: Would this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/gwpsv9y6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a Bootstrap-only solution: ([Example](http://cjo.me/so/29804312/index.html))

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        <h3 class="text-info">A page header here</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 text-right">
          <h5 class="text-info">Owner: <a href="#" target="_blank">Bob Smith</a></h5>
          <h5 class="text-info">Type: Desktop</h5>
          <h5 class="text-info">Status: Active</h5>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Creates:

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I need but the content on the right is starting after the page header (its pushed below it). Is it possible to only have that header go so far so that the content on the right will not be pushed down?

Comment: @SBB I added the responsive classes in order to prevent the right content from popping underneath the heading at any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same row for both elements. Take a look:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="page-header">
        <h3 class="text-info">A page header here</h3>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
  <h5 class="text-info">Owner: <a href="#" target="_blank">Bob Smith</a></h5>
  <h5 class="text-info">Type: Desktop</h5>
  <h5 class="text-info">Status: Active</h5>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jozreLj2/

Comment: While this works, my end goal is that the HR under the header runs all the way across and doesn't cut off

Comment: In that case, I suggest you don't use the page-header class and add the line in another row.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to position the `<div>`with the information first before the `<div>` with the page header. Then apply the class `.pull-right`on the `<div>` with the information.

**Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/rka18Lze/1/)**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row pull-right">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 text-right">
            <h5 class="text-info">Owner: <a href="#" target="_blank">Bob Smith</a></h5>
            <h5 class="text-info">Type: Desktop</h5>
            <h5 class="text-info">Status: Active</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3 class="text-info">A page header here</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```